# Disable automatic user input sanitization

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, user-input, sanitization

I'm setting up a new ASP.NET server, and want to put in HTML that comes from the result of my own filtering method, because I'm already using my own filtering method. But using `@` would automatically sanitize the code using ASP.NET's sanitization method, I don't want this.

I've tried using the `@` symbol to use C# in my Razor Page, but it keeps using ASP.NET's sanitization method.

```cs
public string GetFormattedName(string name)
{
    // Sanitize user input
    return name.Replace("<","&gt;"); // And do my own fancy sanitization.
}
```

```html
<h3>@Model.GetFormattedName("<strong class="bold-tag">etc</strong>")</h3>
```

The rendered HTML looks like:

```
<strong class="bold-tag">etc</strong>
```

but it should be

**etc**

(as rendered HTML)

Also I have a special colour code syntax that goes like this:
`[color:ff0000][/color]`

and I want it to still work, and **not** use ASP.NET's sanitization method

Comment: Actually I think I could cast it to `IHtmlString`. Ref: https://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/dont-call-htmlencode-in-razor.html

Answer (score 0):

Try cast to IHtmString.

Rendered as:

```
<h3>@Html.Raw(Model.GetFormattedName("<strong class="bold-tag">etc</strong>"))</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Try this for example:

```
<h3>@Html.Raw(@"<strong class=""bold-tag"">etc</strong>")</h3>
```

Should be rendered as:

```html
<h3><strong class="bold-tag">etc</strong></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just edited my question for more information, because I don't want the default sanitization method. I already have my own method, that adds colours, so the sanitization method would ruin it. As I can see at the moment, it's using my sanitization method, then decoding it, then finally using ASP.NET's sanitization method, which gets rid of my colours.